# Git: list all files in another branch that are not in the current branch?

Tags: git

```
git diff <other branch> <this branch>
```

will show me all differences, but files that don't exist in the current branch have no special indicator in that list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [the exact same question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28284890).

> You can use `git diff-tree` to achieve what you want
>
> use `-r` to recursively descend through subtree and `--diff-filter` to restrict output to only certain types of diffs (for instance, deletions=D)
>
> `git diff-tree -r --diff-filter=D branchA branchB`

Comment: This is pretty much the simplest what I needed so I'll set this as accepted. Is there a way to hide all the hashes from displaying?

Comment: use with `| awk '{print $NF}'` at the end of the command

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to used "--diff-filter" flag to as like you want:

```
git diff --diff-filter=[D|M|A] branch1 branch2
```

As:

- D: sort files existing in branch1 only.
- M: sort files have been modified
- A: sort files existing in branch2 only.

You can use all of them at the same time, also with "`--stat`" flag for a quick view of the changes.

Comment: great, thank you!

Comment: The option `--name-only` from @CodeWizard's answer is also a useful addition to condense the output.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
git diff --name-only branch1 master
```

Comment: Won't this show all files that differ, not only the missing ones?

Comment: It will show all the changes between the branches, you can filter by the status (deleted) if you need with the `git status` command